# WebDAV публикация в Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, azure, azure-websites

Неделю назад сделал шаблонный MVC проект в VS2015. Залил его в облако под майкросовтовским аккаунтом.

Сегодня заливка стартовать не хочет - выскакивает окошко windows авторизации с каким то техническим пользователем ($< sitename >), пароля для которого я не знаю.
Как следствие неудачная авторизация и проваленный деплой.

Пробовал разные пароли и аккаунты, ничего не подходит.

Кто знает как побороть эту беду?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В новом портале выбираешь твой Azure Website --> All Settings --> Properties --> Deployment Trigger URL

Там будет нечто такое:

```
https://$webSiteName:longLongPasswort@webSiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy
```

`$webSiteName` – это и будет твой "технический" пользователь, а то что после двоеточия пароль от него.